# mysql won't let me change collation type

Tags: mysql, collation

I'm trying to convert my table collation type from unicode to general, but mysql isn't allowing it. No errors are returned, but when I view the table, I can see that no changes are being made.

```
mysql> show variables like '%coll%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table abc;
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| abc_test | CREATE TABLE `abc` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `somecolumn` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> alter table abc convert to charset utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table abc;
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| abc_test | CREATE TABLE `abc` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `somecolumn` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Recommend filing a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use alter like this `ALTER TABLE table_name COLLATE='utf8_general_ci';`

Your table already has `UTF8 charset`. So, In my opinion you don't need to set it again. I can see that you are trying to convert it to charset utf8 again with your alter query.

Comment: I added the reason.

Comment: The `=` is optional in the syntax.  The syntax does not allow `COLLATE` without `CHARACTER SET`; this may be another bug.

Comment: Note that this answer is changing the `DEFAULT` collation, doing a `CONVERT TO`.  This may explain why it worked differently.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with mysql 5.7.18, and everything looks just fine. So which version are you using?

I set the collation variables same as yours, and created table and change the collation by the statements copied from above. And at last I got:

```
mysql> show create table abc;
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| abc   | CREATE TABLE `abc` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `somecolumn` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select version();
+--------------+
| version()    |
+--------------+
| 5.7.18-debug |
+--------------+
```

The "SHOW CREATE TABLE" doesn't print collation info because utf8_general_ci is the default collation of utf8.